# Chrome update broke my scrolling sub-menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Updated Chrome to version 56... in Windows and Osx and it broke my scrolling sub-menus. If I scroll with the mouse wheel, scrolling action works, but when if I hover the mouse pointer over the scroll bar the sub-menu closes.

I use the following css for scrolling sub-menus:

```
ul.scroll-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inherit !important;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -o-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -o-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Before the update everything worked well. It still does in Safari and FireFox.

Anyone have the same problem? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Leandro.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Chrome 56 where hovering over a scroll bar does not trigger a hover on the element: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686678